# как в php передать параметр на странице index.php функцией header

Tags: php, openserver, header

Требуется передать get-параметр на страницу индекс.php, но попытка сделать это таким образом: header('Location: index.php?success') - приводит к провалу. Совсем такой же резульат получается когда: header('Location: ?success'), а вот вариант: header('Location: success') заставляет браузер думать что мы хотим обратиться к несуществующей странице и я его понимаю. Причём в таком варианте: header('Location: test.php?success') всё работает исправно, при наличии конечно файла test.php в текущей папке. Как же всё таки передать этот параметр на страницу?

PS.: Тесты производились с использованием OpenServer, но подозреваю что на реальном хостинге я бы столкнулся с подобным результатом.

Comment: У параметра [должно быть значение](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), просто так указав его имя он не передастся.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov "к провалу" это значит что браузер ругается: " Сайт newproject выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз". Насчёт значения: до сегодняшнего дня я тоже также думал, но оказалось оно не обязательно, и переход на test.php  тому подтверждение.

Comment: Если вы будете перенаправлять на страницу, которая только и будет перенаправлять на себя саму, то у вас получится зацикливание, о чём вам браузер успешно и сообщил

Comment: @ArchDemon это я понял, как же в таком случае передать параметр?

Comment: Так как вы делаете, только не нужно перенаправлять на страницу, которая будет перенаправлять на страницу

Comment: @ArchDemon да я бы и рад, но задача стоит имено так: "Пусть на странице index.php можно передать GET параметр с именем success. Сделайте так, чтобы при наличии такого параметра, на страницу выводилось сообщение об успехе операции."

Comment: а при чем тут header-location в этой задаче? судя по условию, все что требуется от вашего index.php это `<?php if( isset($_GET['success']) ) echo "success!"; ` и все. Как вы сюда прикрутили редирект?

Comment: @teran Условия задачи я взял из урока посвященого данной [теме](http://code.mu/ru/php/book/prime/redirect/get-queries/)

Comment: так там у вас речь про `index.php` с содержимым, которое я привел выше. и второй файл action.php, содержимое которого выглядит как `<?php header("Location: index.php?success")`. Теперь при заходе на action.php вы будете перенаправляться в index.php. Вы же судя по всему почему то решили сделать один файл и получили "циклический редирект".

Comment: @teran Не совесем верно: файл action.php появляется только в задаче 2 и на момент взаимодействия с первой задачей его нет в природе. На счёт циклического редиректа полностью с вами согласен. Видимо, в таком случае можно сделать вывод что данная задача поставлена неккоректно. В любом случае благодарю за участие в обсуждении.

Comment: так в первой задаче вас и не просят использовать header-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком сложно вы с куками намудрили. Всё можно сделать проще:

```
if (!isset($_GET['success'])) {
    header('Location: ?success');
}
else {
    echo 'Success redirect!';
}
```

Comment: Mironov Хм, после нескольких неудачных попыток я отбросил данное решение, а сегодня оно оказалось для меня просто открытием. Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Разрешение данного вопроса я вижу через куки:

```
    if (empty($_COOKIE['success'])) {
      header('Location: ?success');
      if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
        setcookie('success', 'Operation has executed successfully');
      }
    } else {
      echo $_COOKIE['success'];
    };
```

Конечно такое использование весьма малопрактично, но оно работает и решает поставленную задачу